# Using between 2 dates to query data

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 input boxes in a form that I will input beginning date under selDate and end date under selDate2. My table stores the date field in a text field.

```
<form id="formDate" name="formDate" method="post" action="">
      <p><strong>Date Filter:</strong></br>
        </p>
      <p>
        <label for="selDate"></label>
        <input type="text" name="selDate" id="selDate" 
value="<?php echo $_POST['selDate']; ?>" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="selDate2"></label>
        <input type="text" name="selDate2" id="selDate2" 
value="<?php echo $_POST['selDate2']; ?>"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Submit" />

    </form>
```

I am using the following statement to list the corresponding rows.

```
$varDate_Recordset1 = $row_RecordsetLastDate['date'];
if (isset($_POST['selDate'])) {
  $varDate_Recordset1 = $_POST['selDate'];
}
$varDate2_Recordset1 = $row_RecordsetLastDate['date'];
if (isset($_POST['selDate2'])) {
  $varDate2_Recordset1 = $_POST['selDate2'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_port, $port);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM checkout, `transaction`, school_store 
WHERE `transaction`.activity_id=school_store.Tag 
AND `transaction`.transaction_id=checkout.transaction_id AND (checkout.`date` 
BETWEEN %s AND %s) AND `transaction`.status='1' 
ORDER BY checkout.`date` DESC, `transaction`.id DESC", 
GetSQLValueString($varDate_Recordset1, "text"), 
GetSQLValueString($varDate2_Recordset1, "text"));
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $port) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
```

I am using BETWEEN both variables in the query. When input the dates I echo blank rows. I have also tried checkout.`date` BETWEEN CAST(%s AS DATE) AND CAST(%s AS DATE) to no avail. I even tried checkout.`date` >=%s AND checkout.`date` <=%s with no luck. Why is it not displaying the data?

Comment: does the query return rows when your leave the BETWEEN date part out?

Comment: Echo your $query_Recordset1 to see if the query looks like you think it should, and try it on the mysql command line. You should also switch to PDO or mysqli, as the mysql_* functions are removed in PHP7, and deprecated in previous versions. It could possibly help your query.

Comment: Yes. If I do not input dates, the data echoes properly.

Comment: I use RecorsetDateLast to display by default the latest date if no date is selected. That echoes the data fine.

Comment: In what format do you input your dates? By default they should by formatted as 'Y-m-d'

Comment: I am inputting them like 2016-11-01.

Comment: Like what @aynber said, could you post the string '$query_Recordset1'?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Data echoes until I use the input boxes. By default the script echos the last date in MYSQL table.

Comment: What I mean is could you show the contents of the var $query_Recordset1, for instance put the code 'die($query_Recordset1);' in front of the line '$Recordset1 = mysql.....'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127210/discussion-between-peter-m-and-user3258571).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for when others search for this information.

the field `checkout`.`date` was not of the type DATE or DATETIME and therefor was not showing any results with the current query.

Changing field type resolved the problem. (this however could result in data los so be careful).

End query should be (checkout.`date` BETWEEN %s AND %s)

Answer (score 0):

Since your date is in a text field, it can't be used as comparison. You have to cast that column as a date first.

```
(STR_TO_DATE(checkout.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN %s and %s)
```

Make sure that all three are in a `Y-m-d` format, or you may have to convert it.

Comment: Now says query is empty using SELECT * FROM checkout, `transaction`, school_store WHERE `transaction`.activity_id=school_store.Tag AND `transaction`.transaction_id=checkout.transaction_id AND (STR_TO_DATE(checkout.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')) BETWEEN %s AND %s

Comment: Between needs to go between the two `))` in your query. After the STR_TO_TIME but before closing out the AND.

Comment: I am now using (STR_TO_DATE(checkout.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN %s AND %s). I still am getting Query was empty.

Comment: Query was empty is also showing for (STR_TO_DATE(checkout.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN CAST(%s AS DATE) AND CAST(%s AS DATE))

Comment: `Query was empty` means it's not passing the query into `mysql_query`. Did you change anything with that line or change `$query_Recordset1` other than my suggestion?

Comment: I did not change anything else.

Comment: I'm wondering if the `%` symbols in the STR_TO_DATE and the GetSQLValueString functions are incompatible. Another reason to switch to PDO/mysqli...